# Why don't TCP connections automatically close on timeout?

Tags: connection, database-connection, connection-timeout, dolphindb

I use the `getConnections()` function to check the number of active connections:

[image]

I've configured the timeout setting with *tcp_keepalive_time* set to 7200 (i.e., 2 hours).

However, the connections are not automatically closed after the set timeout period. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have they all been *idle* for two hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may be related to the configuration settings on your operating system.

You can close inactive sessions by the following two approaches:

1. When your program exits or the connection is no longer in use, call
   `session.close()`.
2. Set up a server-side scheduled task that invokes the
   [closeInactiveSessions](https://github.com/dolphindb/DolphinDBModules/blob/master/ops/README_EN.md#32-closeinactivesessions) function.